# Median filtering with AVX AVX2 and OpenMP

Tags: x86, openmp, vectorization, avx, avx2

I am working on a median filter using avx avx2 instructions and OpenMP. The input is a 4K picture. At a time the algorithm works on a single color component of a pixel taken from the input.

My filter size is `5*5 = 25`.  To median filter I must sort these  `unsigned char` numbers and then take the middle one. I am using Batcher's Odd-Even mergesort and that is just working fine.

I am at that point where I need to speed up the algorithm as much as I can. I tested the program multiple times and take an average the result was 3.08 seconds

Visualization of the sorting algorithm: as you can see the whole sorting process can be broken up into 15 smaller steps.
[image: Visualization of the sorting algorithm]

---

I have top level function that I call from main named `MedianFiltering` that takes all the information required to do the filtering and writes it back using a pointer. When this function is called it creates all the required control vectors for the following two functions:

`_mm256_blendv_epi8()` and `_mm256_permute2f128_si256()`

### Creating all the required control vectors

I have 40 of the next line (all named differently)

```
__m256i vectorControl= _mm256_lddqu_si256((__m256i *)controlArray);
```

something like :

```
__m256i vmaskBlendControlFromMinMaxandWorkingOn4 = _mm256_lddqu_si256((__m256i *)maskBlendControlFromMinMaxandWorkingOn4);

__m256i vmaskBlendControlFromMinandMax5 = _mm256_lddqu_si256((__m256i *)maskBlendControlFromMinandMax5);
__m256i vmaskBlendControlFromMinMaxandWorkingOn5 = _mm256_lddqu_si256((__m256i *)maskBlendControlFromMinMaxandWorkingOn5);

__m256i vmaskBlendControlFromMinandMax6 = _mm256_lddqu_si256((__m256i *)maskBlendControlFromMinandMax6);

__m256i vmaskBlendControlFromMinandMax7 = _mm256_lddqu_si256((__m256i *)maskBlendControlFromMinandMax7);
__m256i vmaskBlendControlFromMinMaxandWorkingOn7 = _mm256_lddqu_si256((__m256i *)maskBlendControlFromMinMaxandWorkingOn7);
```

I think i don't need to post it all you get the idea.

### Algorithm

then the sorting process:

```
//stepping on every row
for (int row = 0; row < imgHeight; row++)
{
    stepping on every column of the picture

    for (int col = 0; col < imgWidth; col++)
    {
        OneColorChanelWidth calculatedMedians[3] = { 0 };
        //calculating each color of a single pixel
        for (int rgba = 0; rgba < 3; rgba++)
        {
            OneColorChanelWidth calcMedian[] = { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255 };
            for (int fy = 0; fy < FILTER_W; fy++)
            {
                for (int fx = 0; fx < FILTER_H; fx++)
                {
                    calcMedian[fy * 5 + fx] = *(imgSrcExt + (row + fy)*imgWidthF * 3 + (col + fx) * 3 + rgba);
                }
            }
            __m256i vinput = _mm256_lddqu_si256((__m256i *)calcMedian);


              *Sorting the calcMedian array all the 15 steps are here the result is stored in workingOn*



            *(imgDstMedian + row*imgWidth * 3 + col * 3 + rgba) = workingOn.m256i_u8[12];
        }
    }
}
```

Bird's-eye view point:

```
void MedianFiltering(arguments)
{

   Creating all the required control vectors

   Algorithm

   return;
}
```

---

Since I can use OpenMP, parallelization can be good to improve processing speed. I put `#pragma omp parallel for` in front of the `for` loop that counts by rows but nothing changed.  Then I put it in front of the one that counts by rows, no speed gain.

After this I am thinking about maybe the problem is that all the threads that start use the same control vectors (they all read by the way) please tell me if this can causes that the parallelization can't make any difference.

I have done an experiment: I put this parallelization pragma to different places in the code and run tests,but unfortunately none of the experiments showed a high speed improvement. **Actually 3.08 seconds was the lowest time I got but this can be achieved without any parallellizaiton.**

**Is there a way using parallelization to improve my processing time?** The other way would involve redo the sorting process, but i am not interested in that at the moment.

Comment: Instead of `_mm256_blendv_epi8()`, you should be able to use [`_mm256_min_epu8`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/PMINUB:PMINUW.html) and `_mm256_max_epu8` as comparators in your sorting network.  For packed RGB, you might be able to do all 3 color components in parallel, and unpack the vector at the end.  Or it might be a win to unpack the whole image to a planar format and then parallelize the median filtering over each component separately.

Comment: I am using those min and max functions for comparison and then with blendv put those vectors together

Comment: You can use `vshufps` or maybe `vpalignr` to combine data from 2 vectors more efficiently (1 uop) than `vblendvb` (2 uops).  Or `vpblendd` is very good if you can use a blend with 32-bit granularity.  `vpblendw` only runs on port 5 on Intel (like shuffles), but is a single uop.

Comment: I will try them out this weekend.